# Asyncio - schedule multiple tasks to run on the current loop while other task running

Tags: python, loops, python-asyncio

I'm tring to write a simple robot that shows the user a textual menu with few options and than wait for user input.
The user should be able to select a task from the menu and have the task addedd to run in the asyncio loop, when the task is scheduled it should run in the background while the user is presented again with the menu to make a new selection if needed/wanted.

```
import asyncio

class aRobot:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        self.isrunning = True
        self.tasks = {}

    async def asleep(self) -> None:
        await asyncio.sleep(20)
        print("asleep completed")     

    async def start(self) -> None:
        while self.isrunning:
            async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
                task1 = tg.create_task(self.menu())
                task2 = tg.create_task(self.get_input())

    async def menu(self) -> None:
        print("1. Add task1")
        print("3. Check all tasks")
        print("5. Exit")

    async def get_input(self):
        usr_input = input('==> ')
        await self.select_task(int(usr_input))
  
    async def select_task(self,input: int):
        if input == 1:
            self.schedule_task(self.asleep)
        elif input == 3:
            await self.check_tasks()
        elif input == 5:
            self.isrunning = False
        else:
            pass

    async def schedule_task(self, coro_func):
        task = self.loop.create_task(coro_func)
 
    async def check_tasks(self):
        tasks = asyncio.all_tasks()
        for task in tasks:
            print(f'> {task.get_name()}, {task.get_coro()}')


if __name__ == "__main__":

    robot = aRobot()
    asyncio.run(robot.start())
```

The above code do not fully perform as expected, while the menu is presented selecting multiple times "1", in my expectation should add to the loop an equal number of asleep tasks that simply wait 20 second.
If than user select "3" before the 20 second elapsed he should be presented with as many "asleep" task he has scheduled and that are not yet completed. However only "start" and "input" seems to be in the loop.

```
1. Add task1
3. Check all tasks
5. Exit
==> 1
/Code/Pycode/AsyncRobot.py:33: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'aRobot.schedule_task' was never awaited
  self.schedule_task(self.asleep)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
1. Add task1
3. Check all tasks
5. Exit
==> 3
> Task-1, <coroutine object aRobot.start at 0x7fa58b259740>
> Task-5, <coroutine object aRobot.get_input at 0x7fa58b26a260>
```

Answer (score 0):

All tasks inside a `TaskGroup` will complete when the `with` block containing them ends.

In this case, this means that each pair of `menu` and `get_input` (which will not only get the input, but also execute the option) will have to run to completion before the menu is presented again.

What you should do is another co-routine function that will do everything you need in order, in order: print the menu, and get the input - but *only get the input*, not execute it. Because after getting the input, you are ready to print the menu again. Then you "create a task" to execute the actual task, and the menu and inputs can continue to happen concurrently. The "taskgroup" is either not needed there, or, you can place it outter to the `while True` statement - so that when one choose to exit, you exit the TG, and all tasks are completed before any other are added.

Also, another problem you have there is you are using plain `input`: it is a blocking function, and nothing will run while the input prompt waits for the user to press "enter".
There are 3rdy party libraries that have asynchronous versions of input - I put `terminedia.ainput` in the code, you can install terminedia with `pip install terminedia`. Async input is a bit messy, because if other task prints something while it is waiting for the user input, that content will be placed where the user should type. That can't be easily corrected, but for making of your program a full blown TUI (text user interface) program - or taking some care using locks and queues, instead of printing directly from the tasks. In order for not to overcomplicate things, I just added the `ainput` in a way running tasks will keep running in the background. (you could also just reprint the menu if the input comes out empty, and instruct the user to just press "enter" if the terminal print things over the prompt)

```
import asyncio

from terminedia import ainput

class aRobot:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        self.isrunning = True
        self.tasks = {}

    async def asleep(self) -> None:
        await asyncio.sleep(20)
        print("asleep completed")     

    async def start(self) -> None:
        async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
            while self.isrunning:
                await tg.create_task(self.menu())
                option = await tg.create_task(self.get_input())
                tg.create_task(option)  # this is run concurrently.

    async def menu(self) -> None:
        print("1. Add task1")
        print("3. Check all tasks")
        print("5. Exit")

    async def get_input(self):
        usr_input = await ainput('==> ')
        return int(user_input)
        
  
    async def select_task(self,input: int):
        if input == 1:
            self.schedule_task(self.asleep)
        elif input == 3:
            await self.check_tasks()
        elif input == 5:
            self.isrunning = False
        else:
            pass

    async def schedule_task(self, coro_func):
        task = self.loop.create_task(coro_func)
 
    async def check_tasks(self):
        tasks = asyncio.all_tasks()
        for task in tasks:
            print(f'> {task.get_name()}, {task.get_coro()}')


if __name__ == "__main__":

    robot = aRobot()
    asyncio.run(robot.start())
```